# Delete local printers with (copy #)

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I'm trying to create batch file to remove local copies of printers. I'm working with printers of same models, so daily I get about 10-20 printer_name(copy #) instances in printer list. Removing those manually is quite tedious process. So I decided to find a way to automate it. And I need to remove those only with (copy #)

My first idea was simple `rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /dl /n "printer_name("*`, which obviously didn't work, because wildcards do not work like that. So to address the problem I could use `findstr` or `find`. For which I need a list, in my situation list of printers. So I got list of printers with `wmic printer get name` and here I hit a dead end. Since there would be a lot of printers, best case scenario would be to assign the list to an array and then create loop to check for required printers from the array and delete them. Where `set list = wmic printer get name` came with an error. I would assume I need to use `/n` to tell the script, that new line is new entry in the array. But I have no idea how to parse the result of wmic into an array

I'm open for better ideas on how to remove required printers if there is any or I'll appreciate any help on attaching list to an array. Because `wmic printer get name` prints something like this

```
printer1
printer2
printer2(copy 1)
printer2(copy 2)
printer3
printer3(copy 1)
```

And as I mentioned before, I would need to remove only printer2(copy 1), printer2(copy 2) and printer3(copy 1)

Thank you in advance

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('wmic printer get name ^| findstr "(copy"') do echo Remove: %%a`

Comment: Or possibly; from a [tag:batch-file], `WMIC Printer Where "Name Like '%%Copy%%'" Delete`; from [tag:cmd], `WMIC Printer Where "Name Like '%Copy%'" Delete`.

Answer (score 1):

Found a super easy solution. And if anybody needs it, it looks like this

```
wmic printer where (name like '%%(copy %%') delete
```

Credits go to ConstanceJill

Comment: Oh, sorry. Page didn't update, if you want I can delete mine, you add yours and I'll mark it as an answer? =D

Comment: No, it's yours! If you want you can include my comment information, to show at least the [tag:cmd] version.